# AngularJS dindn't work in firefox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I wrote a login for a web-application. In chrome the login works but not in firefox.

```
<form ng-submit="$ctrl.login()">
   <div class="cClearFloat">
      <input type="text" name="Benutzername" placeholder="Benutzername" ng-model="$ctrl.userName">
   </div>
      <div class="cClearFloat">
         <input type="password" name="Passwort" placeholder="Passwort" ng-model="$ctrl.password">
      </div>
      <div class="cClearFloat">
         <div class="cButtonLogin" class="button">
            <button class="cLinkLogin" type="submit">Anmelden</button>
         </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

login call:

```
login() {
    this.userService.login(this.userName, this.password);
}
```

login:

```
login(userName, password) {
   this.$http.post("http://localhost:20670/login", { UserName: userName, Password: password }).then((response) => {
      this.userInfo = this.hateoasService.fromData(response.data);
      this.$http.defaults.headers.common.LoginToken = this.userInfo.LoginToken;
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
}, (response) => {
   swal({
      title: response.data.error,
      type: 'error'
   })
 });
}
```

All what happens when I test it in firefox is that it reloads the page. Does someone know why it's not working? Is it possible that it makes the reload is because angularjs isn't available and he takes the default from ng-submit?

in my console I had this error

[image]

Comment: I used to use <form name="myForm" .... <button disabled="!myForm.valid()" onclick="$ctrl.login()" class="cLinkLogin" type="submit">Anmelden</button> or something similiar.

Comment: Looking at your console error the error isn't in your form but in some object invocation. Please check the stack trace of your console error.

Comment: the stacktrace goes for angular.min.js file

Comment: Then use the non-minified angular for debugging purposes. Those stacktraces will be more descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-submit` on your `form` and change the button type to `submit`

On your view:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="login()">
        <input type="text" name="Benutzername" placeholder="Benutzername" ng-model="model.userName">
        <input type="password" name="Passwort" placeholder="Passwort" ng-model="model.password">
        <button class="cLinkLogin" type="submit">Anmelden</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

On controller :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.login = function() {
        alert("username: " + $scope.model.userName + ", password: " + $scope.model.password);
    }
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNgvJp?editors=1010